# Adding Lambda Expression to DisplaySettingsChanged event handler in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, eventhandler

I was creating a C# WPF custom control library, My library uses `DisplaySettingsChanged` event from SystemEvents Class, In the Docs Microsoft mentioned about detaching the Event Handler.

> Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers
> when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.

So will it be possible to use lambda expression without causing memory leak in the program *( without using -= )*.

Which means :

Can I use this:

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += (_, _) =>
{
   // My code Here
};
```

instead of using this:

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += OnDisplaySettingsChanged;
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= OnDisplaySettingsChanged; // Calling this in Dispose Method
```

### Full Code

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace FluentCompositor.Core
{
    public sealed class CompositionMetrics : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly HwndSource hwndSource;

        public CompositionMetrics(HwndSource source)
        {
            hwndSource = source;
            SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += OnDisplaySettingsChanged; //added event handler over here
        }

        private void OnDisplaySettingsChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= OnDisplaySettingsChanged; // disposing event handler here
        }

        #region Properties

        public int Width
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public double ScaleFactor
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Docs explicitly say that you must unsubscribe or memory leak will occur, and you ask if you can ignore unsubscribe without causing memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Lambda is anonymous, so you will not able to detach event and thus will cause a memory leak.

I think, you can store you lambda in the class-level field, and then use this value to detach event, but it is almost the same as the approach with the ordinal handler without lambda.

Comment: Thank you, is detaching the event handler in dispose() is an appropriate method ?

Comment: Yes, detaching in the `Dispose` is absolutely appropriate. Just take into account that it is absolutely up to developer's responsibility to call `Dispose` for the object. And if developer will not call it, you will have a leak.

Comment: Sure I am using this class for internal use and it won't be exposed outside the library. i will use internal access specifier and will call Dispose on the class where I use the object of CompositionMetrics. Thankyou